# System.UnauthorizedAccessException only using multithreading

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, runtime-error

I wrote a code to parse some Web tables.

I get some web tables into an `IHTMLElementCollection` using Internet Explorer with this code:

```
TabWeb = IE.document.getelementsbytagname("table")
```

Then I use a sub who gets an object containing the `IHTMLElementCollection` and some other data:

```
Private Sub TblParsing(ByVal ArrVal() As Object)
    Dim WTab As mshtml.IHTMLElementCollection = ArrVal(0)
    'some code
End sub
```

My issue is: if I simply "call" this code, it works correctly:

```
Call TblParsing({WTab, LiRow})
```

but, if I try to run it into a threadpool:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(New WaitCallback(AddressOf TblParsing), {WTab, LiRow})
```

the code fails and give me multiple

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException

This happens on (each of) these code rows:

```
Rws = WTab(RifWT("Disc")).Rows.Length 

If Not IsError(WTab(6).Cells(1).innertext) Then
    Ogg_W = WTab(6).Cells(1).innertext
```

My goal is to navigate to another web page while my sub perform parsing.

I want to clarify that:

1) I've tryed to send the entire HTML to the sub and get it into a `webbrowser` but it didn't work because it isn't possible to cast from `System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElementCollection` to `mshtml.IHTMLElementCollection` (or I wasn't able to do it);

2) I can't use `WebRequest` and similar: I'm forced to use `InternetExplorer`;

3) I can't use `System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElementCollection` because my parsing code uses `Cells`, `Rows` and so on that are unavailable (and I don't want to rewrite all my parsing code)

EDIT:

Ok, I modified my code using answer hints as below:

```
'This in the caller sub
Dim IE As Object = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
'...some code
Dim IE_Body As String = IE.document.body.innerhtml
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(New WaitCallback(AddressOf TblParsing_2), {IE_Body, LiRow})
'...some code

'This is the called sub
Private Sub TblParsing_2(ByVal ArrVal() As Object)
    Dim domDoc As New mshtml.HTMLDocument
    Dim domDoc2 As mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 = CType(domDoc, mshtml.IHTMLDocument2)
    domDoc2.write(ArrVal(0))

    Dim body As mshtml.IHTMLElement2 = CType(domDoc2.body, mshtml.IHTMLElement2)
    Dim TabWeb As mshtml.IHTMLElementCollection = body.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")
    '...some code
```

I get no errors but I'm not sure that it's all right because I tryed to use `IE_Body` string into webbrowser and it throws errors in the webpage (it shows a popup and I can ignore errors).

Am I using the right way to get `Html` from `Internet Explorer` into a `string`?

EDIT2:

I changed my code to:

```
Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer  
'... some code
Dim sourceIDoc3 As mshtml.IHTMLDocument3 = CType(IE.Document, mshtml.IHTMLDocument3)
Dim html As String = sourceIDoc3.documentElement.outerHTML
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(New WaitCallback(AddressOf TblParsing_2), {html, LiRow})
'... some code

Private Sub TblParsing_2(ByVal ArrVal() As Object)
    Dim domDoc As New mshtml.HTMLDocument
    Dim domDoc2 As mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 = CType(domDoc, mshtml.IHTMLDocument2)
    domDoc2.write(ArrVal(0))
    Dim body As mshtml.IHTMLElement2 = CType(domDoc2.body, mshtml.IHTMLElement2)
    Dim TabWeb As mshtml.IHTMLElementCollection = body.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")
```

But I get an error PopUp like (I tryed to translate it):
Title:

> Web page error

Text:

> Debug this page?
>   This page contains errors that might prevent the proper display or function properly.
>   If you are not testing the web page, click No.

two checkboxes

> do not show this message again
>   Use script debugger built-in Internet Explorer

It's the same error I got trying to get Html text into a WebBrowser.
But, If I could ignore this error, I think the code could work!

While the pop is showing I get error on

```
Dim domDoc As New mshtml.HTMLDocument
```

Error text translated is:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {25336920-03F9-11CF-8FD0-00AA00686F13} failed due to the following error: The 8,001,010th message filter indicated that the application is busy. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010A (RPC_E_SERVERCALL_RETRYLATER)).

Note that I've alredy set `IE.silent = True`

Comment: You cannot interact with UIControls from a background thread, you should separate the data from UIControls before sending it to your background thread, or check if InvokeRequired is necessary for each UI control before you get the values

Comment: @Icepickle I thought that passing "for value" meant to secure the contents of the variable. So I thought that it was possible to open another web page while  the thread does its job. Is this wrong? How can I do so?

Comment: When you call the thread actually you make a redirection? If yes, try to leave the page loaded without changing it

Comment: @bdn02 But my goal it's just to navigate to another web page!

Comment: Is this extension of your old question?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31650782/strange-unauthorizedaccessexception, you can update old one.

Comment: @AnilKumar No. The old question refer to another project.

Comment: You have access to the Webbrowser.DocumentText property (its HTML).  There are several possible solutions paths to follow with that.  You are using mshtml, so you could create a new mshtml.HTMLDocument and write the HTML string to that document by casting to mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 and calling the "write" method.

Comment: @TnTinMn I tryed something similar using a `webbroser` instance: I was able to get `IE.document.body.InnerHtml` and put it into my  `webbroser` (I don't know if I did it right) but I wasn't able to create an object `mshtml.IHTMLElementCollection` from webbrowser. If you are able to do this you've got my answer! So can you please help me?

Comment: Set Option Strict On.  You are relying on implicit conversions in your code and those are subject to errors.  In particular, the TblParsing_2 method signature is incorrect for the [WaitCallback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waitcallback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) delegate.  Set the browser's `Silent` property to true before navigating to the Url.

Answer (score 1):

Edit:  There was confusion as to what the OP meant by "Internet Explorer".  I originally assumed that it meant the WinForm Webbrowser control; however the OP is creating the COM browser directly instead of using the .Net wrapper.

To get the browser document's defining HTML, you can cast the document against the `mshtml.IHTMLDocument3` interface to expose the `documentElement` property.

```
Dim ie As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer  ' Proj COM Ref: Microsoft Internet Controls
ie.Navigate("some url")
' ... other stuff
Dim sourceIDoc3 As mshtml.IHTMLDocument3 = CType(ie.Document, mshtml.IHTMLDocument3)
Dim html As String = sourceIDoc3.documentElement.outerHTML
```

End Edit.

---

The following is based on my comment above.  You use the [`WebBrowser.DocumentText` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documenttext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to create a `mshtml.HTMLDocument`.

> Use this property when you want to manipulate the contents of an HTML page displayed in the WebBrowser control using string processing tools.

Once you extract this property as a String, there is no connection to the WebBrowser control and you can process the data in any thread you want.

```
Dim html As String = WebBrowser1.DocumentText

Dim domDoc As New mshtml.HTMLDocument
Dim domDoc2 As mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 = CType(domDoc, mshtml.IHTMLDocument2)
domDoc2.write(html)

Dim body As mshtml.IHTMLElement2 = CType(domDoc2.body, mshtml.IHTMLElement2)
Dim tables As mshtml.IHTMLElementCollection = body.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")

' ... do something

' cleanup COM objects
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(body)
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(tables)
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(domDoc)
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(domDoc2)
```

Comment: We're near to a solution! See my edit but note: I'm using `Internet Explorer` not `WebBrowser`.

Comment: It gives me error but if I check "ignore" on the popup the code seems to work. How can I set the code to automatically ignore? (See my edit2)

Comment: @genespos, the code that protects you from the issues of multithrerading as you originally posted.  The code was tested before posting and works assuming you pass it a valid html document source string.  I have also shown you how to obtain that html source from a document.  However, that assumes you have a valid document to start with and that is a whole other issue.  The IE browser can throw up several different dialogs and the methods of dealing with those vary on the dialog and should be a separate question.  Test the code using this url:  "http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp"

Comment: Errors (I think) are on scripts that don't interest me. My only problem is to avoid runtime error: I only want to ignore these errors and the code will work! Can you help me to do this?

Comment: You don't solved all my problems but you were the only one who tryed to help me,so I gave you the bounty ;)